# Проверка скачивания файла с сервера, через сайт

Tags: python-3.x, django, html5

Пытаюсь сделать небольшой текст-ссылку на файл, дабы пользователь мог скачать его:

```html
<div class="w-auto mx-auto">
   <p><a href="123.docx" target="_blank">123</a>
</div>
```

Но при попытке его скачать выводится 404-ая страница. Сейчас файл лежит на компьютере (винда 11), а потом будет лежать на сервере, как понимаю это защита винды не позволяет скачивать файл с компьютера.

**Так вот**

Можете подсказать, как проводить проверки корректности работы данного момента, кроме как создавать "чистый" html (с телом из кода выше), который можно запускать без локалки?

Comment: Запускайте веб-сервер на компьютере и проверяйте. Да и вообще лучше всего полностью повторить серверное окружение на своём компьютере

Answer (score 0):

Це джанго не пропускає

Копайте тут, джанго медіа:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/' #например
MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/files/media' #например